# jQuery: Dropdown option based off the previous dropdown selection

Tags: jquery

I am trying to populate the second dropdown box based on the selection of the first. 
I did my research and found that most of the suggestions/solutions provided are pre loaded with dropdown values.

I am trying to access the database and get the values. I was able to pull this off in Javascript but i found that the Jquery solution would be effective as i have lot of items in the database.

So here is what i have so far. Any suggestions on how I can use MySQL queries to retrieve data from the database and autopopulate ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".countryDropDown").change(function() {
        var country = $(this).val();
        function fillStateDropDown(countryStateOption) {
            $.each(countryStateOption, function(val, text) {
                $('.stateDropDown').append(
                $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text));
            });
        }
        function clearStateDropDown() {
            $('.stateDropDown option:gt(0)').remove();
        }
        if (country == 'INDIA') {
            clearStateDropDown();
            var indiaStateOption = {
                RAJASTHAN: 'Rajasthan',
                GUJRAT: 'Gujrat',
                MAHARASTRA: 'Maharastra'
            };
            fillStateDropDown(indiaStateOption);
        }
        else if (country == 'UK') {
            clearStateDropDown();
            var ukStateOption = {
                LONDON: 'London',
                LIVERPOOL: 'Liverpool',
                DERBY: 'Derby'
            };
            fillStateDropDown(ukStateOption);
        }
        else if (country == 'USA') {
            clearStateDropDown();
            var usaStateOption = {
                CALIFORNIA: 'California',
                TEXAS: 'Texas',
                NEWYORK: 'New York'
            };
            fillStateDropDown(usaStateOption);
        }
        var stateOptions = {
            val1: 'text1',
            val2: 'text2'
        };
    });
});​
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a project right now that implements the exact functionality that you are mentioning here. My implementation is a bit long to show you so I will tell you that you need AJAX and JSON to pass values to PHP, which will handle all the database portion of your project.

Think MVC architecture. Your Views will be your .html files containing HTML/Javascript working together with your .js files containing JQuery/AJAX/JSON.

From your .js files you will use AJAX to call your Controllers, a.k.a. .php files, which should ONLY contain PHP functions. These will handle any incoming data you give it, in your case the ID of your drop down menu and VALUE that was selected from the drop down, which you will use JQuery to get.

From your Controller file you will call functions in your Model, another .php file containing functions that will handle the SQL queries according to your needs.

It sounds like a lot, it can be if you are not comfortable with MVC style of coding, but I assure you it's not difficult to implement, you just need to make sure that your AJAX/JSON/JQuery are doing what they're supposed to do, then the PHP should handle the rest.

Thankfully there is a lot out there about what's called "using JQuery Mobile with MVC". Get started by going into: http://jquerymobile.com/resources/ and reading on these projects.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks much for the input. I have limited knowledge with MVC and im beginner with jQuery. I just started this week. I'll try and research more and use your suggestions.

Comment: Sure, if you continue to have questions just let me know, I have gone through the learning curve myself so I relate to the task ahead of you. P.S.: the best way to say thanks is to up vote or accept the answer :) good luck again!